# How to find (a*b)%m for large a and b?

Tags: math, numbers, theory, modulo

I have searched on google. On one site it is said that (a*b)%m = a%m*b%m and on another site i found (a*b)%m = (a%m*b%m)%m. So which is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is incorrect. for example, if m is 10, and a and b are 9, then (a%m)=9, (b%m)=9, and  (a%m)(b%m) is 18 - greater than m!

Comment: Wow! Thanks how could i have forgotten to do self analysis of those 2 :( . Sorry guys!